# IQueryable and sorting

Tags: linq

It seems like that after receiving an IQueryable, **I am not able to modify the query** to enable a sort. Here is the code snippet. 
I am under the impression that with IQueryable (as opposed to do IEnumerable) I should be able to do what I am attempting.

```
using (oc1 = new NWEntities())
{
    string customerid = "ALFKI";
    var q = GetOrders((o) => o.CustomerID == customerid);

    q.OrderBy(o => o.ShipCity);   // DOES NOT WORK !!!!!!!!
    foreach (var x in q)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Order#:{0} City:{1} for Customer {2}",
                                    x.OrderID,
                                    x.ShipCity,
                                    customerid));
    }
}

// Returns IQueryable
IQueryable<Order> GetOrders(Expression<Func<Order, Boolean>> predicate)
{            
    return (oc1.Orders.Where(predicate));            
}
```

The output is somehow not sorted by City. Am I missing something obvious ?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Queryable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store the result of `OrderBy` in another variable.  You sorted the list, and then silently dropped the result, and did your iteration on the original:

```
var q = GetOrders(...);

// notice I store in **q2**
var q2 = q.OrderBy(o => o.ShipCity);
foreach (var x in q2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought one could keep building on the linq query variable and it would keep adding to the expression tree until you actually executed the query (by doing .ToList(), foreach(), etc.).   Also, the code works regardless of whether I return IEnumerable or IQueryable. Again, I thought (mistakenly it seems) that one could only modify a query if it is of type IQueryable.

Comment: @Rahul: You are correct.  You can do that, however, you have to store each additional result in another variable.  Just calling `q.OrderBy(o => o.ShipCity)` does nothing as you have observed.  You need to do `var q2 = q.OrderBy(o => o.ShipCity)` to store the result somewhere.

Comment: @Rahul: You can use `LINQ` methods on `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.  The difference is that `IQueryable` will combine the calls lazily and not actually evaluate until the results are requested.  `IEnumerable` however will perform the `LINQ` immediately on the in-memory collection instead of lazy evaluation.  When using LINQ-to-whatever, you should use IQueryable to combine multiple query calls for best performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to clarify.